# Why my C code is slowed down if I am using += operator

Tags: c, performance, operator-keyword

> **Edit**
> I remove some part of the question because it might be confusing > and thanks of answers I should be able to found out by myself.

I am trying to write a program that resample a signal using a spectral function. I am writing the code in C but I discover the problem coding in C++.

Here is a portion of the code I am using. I have a function `test()` that call another function `test3(tmp)` passing an array as pointer. As long as I combine the `+=` operator and I am trying to fill the array of the first function, my code is slowing down.

> I initialize and calculate using zeros but all arrays must have double values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test3(double *tmp);

void test() {
    double *tmp;
    int k;
    tmp = (double *) calloc(250 * 6, sizeof(double));
    for (k = 0; k < 1000; ++k)
        test3(tmp);
    free(tmp);
}

void test3(double *tmp) {
    int k;
    double *fx;
    double *srf;
    double *ptr;
    int p;
    int l;
    int c;
    double a;
    fx = (double *) calloc(2100 * 6, sizeof(double));
    srf = (double *) calloc(2100 * 250, sizeof(double));
    
    for (int k = 0; k < 2100 * 6; ++k)   fx[k] = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 2100 * 250; ++k) srf[k] = 0;
    
    ptr = (double *) calloc(250 * 6, sizeof(double));
    
    for (p = 0; p < 6; ++p) {
        for (l = 0; l < 250; ++l) {
            ptr[l + p*250] = 0.0;
            for (c = 0; c < 2100; ++c)
                ptr[l+p*250] += fx[c+p*2100] * srf[c+l*2100];
        }
    }
    for (k = 0; k < 250 * 6; ++k) tmp[k] = ptr[k];
    
    free(ptr);
    free(fx);
    free(srf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile using:

```
gcc -O2 -o test test.c -lm
```

When I run the code `time ./test` I get

```
./test_lut  3.84s user 0.11s system 98% cpu 4.008 total
```

Comment: Without writing to `tmp` the function has no side effects and can be optimized out, so that part should come as no surprise. Similarly, code which performs addition is slower than code which doesn't...

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does a good job at optimizing out useless code, but not always:

- if you remove the line `for (k = 0; k < 250*6; ++k) tp[k] = ptr[k];` you essentially remove all side effects of the function `test3()`: you initialize arrays pointed to by `fx` and `srf` and compute the entries in the one pointed to by `ptr`, then free these arrays.  The compiler seems able to determine that no object is impacted that survives after returning from the function and removes the code altogether, resulting in almost no time spent in the function.
- if you change `+=` to `=`, the loop

  ```
            for (c = 0; c < 2100; ++c)
                ptr[l+p*250] += fx[c+p*2100] * srf[c+l*2100];
  ```

  keep modifying the same location, hence only the last iteration is useful so the code is reduced to `ptr[l+p*250] += fx[2099+p*2100] * srf[2099+l*2100];` resulting in much faster operation.
- the third attempt using a temporary variable `a` has no impact as the compiler probably already optimizes the constant destination out of the loop.

You can investigate the compiler work using [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jcx8qPK64) and play with the code and compiler flags.

As can be seen analyzing the code generated, neither **gcc** not **clang** generate any code for the initialization loops (setting memory allocated with `calloc()` to all bit zero value `0.0` has no effect) and convert the final `for` loop to a call to `memcpy`.  Commenting this final `for` loop causes both compilers to generate no code and changing the `+=` to `=` simplifies the inner loop code.

Interestingly, albeit both compilers correctly determine that `fx` and `srf` point to arrays with all elements equal to `0.0`, they do not assume that the contents of these arrays stay null for the whole computation and thus all results in the destination array should be null too as `ptr[l+p*250] += fx[c+p*2100] * srf[c+l*2100];` simplifies to `ptr[l+p*250] += 0.0;`

If you compile the code as C (not C++) and define `fx`, `srf` and `ptr` as

```
    double * restrict fx;
    double * restrict srf; 
    double * restrict ptr;
```

Both compilers should determine that the arrays `fx` and `srf` cannot be modified as a side effect of writing via `ptr`, hence remain null.  The code generated would be drastically simplified and should execute almost instantly, but this optimisation does not seem to be effective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check with the Godbolt's Compiler Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

When `for (k = 0; k < 250*6; ++k) tmp[k] = ptr[k];` is removed, `test3` has no side effects (produces no results for the program), and [the compiler optimizes `main` to the two instructions `xor eax, eax` and `ret`](https://godbolt.org/z/YbhMPMdTa).

When `+=` is changed to `=`, the value left in `ptr[l+p*250]` by `ptr[l+p*250] = fx[c+p*2100] * srf[c+l*2100];` is only that of the last iteration of `for (c = 0; c < 2100; ++c)`, so the compiler is able to replace the loop with a single iteration in which `c` is 2099.